# Crop functionality of Aviary is not working | Android

Tags: android, crop, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I have integrated Aviary Photo editor in my Android App.

I am passing the tools below-

```
 String[] tools = new String[]{"SHARPNESS", "EFFECTS",
                "REDEYE",
                "CROP",
                "WHITEN", "DRAW", "STICKERS", "TEXT", "BLEMISH", "MEME",
                "ORIENTATION", "ENHANCE", "FRAMES", "SPLASH", "FOCUS", "BLUR",
                "VIGNETTE", "LIGHTING", "COLOR", "OVERLAYS"};
        newIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_TOOLS_LIST, tools);
```

But the cropping is not working.

**EDIT**

Cropping is Working now BUT when i get the bitmap from `mMainController.getBitmap` then it still returns origin bitmap (WITHOUT Cropped).

Here is my code -

```
@Override
public void onApplyClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mMainController.onApply();
    SaveBitmap(mMainController.getBitmap());//This is returning original bimap NOT CROPPED.
}
```

Comment: Please let us know what version of Aviary/Creative SDK you are using. [Info on the latest version can be found here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

For the recent versions of the Creative SDK Image Editor component (formerly Aviary), you can set the tool list using an array of `ToolLoaderFactory.Tools`.

## Making the array

As an example:

```
ToolLoaderFactory.Tools[] tools = {
    ToolLoaderFactory.Tools.CROP, 
    ToolLoaderFactory.Tools.TEXT};
```

`ToolLoaderFactory.Tools` is an enum, so Android Studio will show you an auto-complete list of the available tools that you can choose from.

## Configuring the Image Editor

You would then pass `tools` to the `AdobeImageIntent.Builder` using the `.withToolList()` method, like this:

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
    .setData(uri)
    .withToolList(tools)
    .build();
```

(Note that since v0.9.7 of the Creative SDK, `AviaryIntent` has been renamed to `AdobeImageIntent`.)

## More info

For more info, [see this blog post on the Creative SDK blog](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2015/10/customizing-the-image-editor-tools-android).

Comment: Hi Ash Ryan,

I am getting an issue while cropping an Image.

Comment: The edited image comes back in the `onActivityResult()` method. For a basic sample of setting this up, see [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/app/src/main/java/com/adobe/imageeditorui/MainActivity.java) in [this sample GitHub repo](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/tree/master/image-editor-ui).